# How can i get price in woocommerce cart product title hook

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

I am working on woocommerce cart page with add_filter "woocommerce_in_cart_product_title", There I want to show price with title.

Like "Product title ($price)"

i have tried this code, but i can not get price.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product_title', 'cart_product_title', 20, 3);

function cart_product_title( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    print_r($items);
    foreach ($items as $cart_item_key => $values) {
            echo $name = $values['prodaddons'][0]['name'].' --- ';
            echo $price = $values['prodaddons'][0]['price'].'<br>';
        }
    echo 'aaaa-'.$title.'-'.$pricees;
}
```

Comment: When using a filter you must use `return` and not `echo`, try changing it and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Yes i know, But my question was about price, i am not getting price value with in the function.

Comment: The code that you've posted above is that the same code you are using? If yes, then on the last line where is `$pricees` defined?

Comment: actually that is $price not $pricees.
$price have products prices, but its show all cart products prices in loop. i am not able to get one product price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'cart_product_title', 20, 3);

function cart_product_title( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    return $title . ' - ' . $values[ 'line_total' ] . '€';
}
```

I don't know your version of woocommerce but woocommerce_in_cart_product_title is depreciated, it's why I use woocommerce_cart_item_name, so you should try both ;)

Comment: Thanks for Answer,
i have try your sulotion, but $values['price'] is not returning price value.

Comment: is there something else?

Comment: What is your version of woocommerce ?

Comment: woocommerce Version: 2.2.8

Comment: Try the answer above, should work. I've edited since yesterday

Comment: Thank you very much, its working now.
i have another question. how can i add addition cost in total?

Comment: I am asking about product total not cart total and not product price.

Comment: Post another question to be more specific and don't forget to accept my answer :p

Comment: Ok i will post new question. This is my first question and i dont know how to accept your answer :( 
can you tell me how i do it?
Thanks,

Comment: This is my new question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134637/woocommerce-how-can-i-add-additional-cost-in-cart-product-total-price