# woocommerce, how can i add additional cost in cart product total price?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add additional cost in the cart **product total price**, not in product price nor the whole cart total price. I am referring about the product total price.

Right now i have not not try and I don't have any code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'function add_additional_price' );
function add_additional_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
// Change the line total price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 'calculate_discounted_price', 10, 2 );
// Display the line total price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'display_discounted_price', 10, 2 );

function calculate_discounted_price( $price, $values ) {
    // You have all your data on $values;
    $price += 10;
    return $price;
}

// wc_price => format the price with your own currency
function display_discounted_price( $values, $item ) {
    return wc_price( $item[ 'line_total' ] );
}
```

Comment: code is not working, i think functions are not calling in hook. 
can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Yes, i Forgot to change function name

Comment: Thanks for answer, its also working. But getting a problem from previous answer.
"Show price with product title." that was also working, but total price showing with title and i want to show actual product price.
Please help.
This is previous question link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035312/how-can-i-get-price-in-woocommerce-cart-product-title-hook/27068018

Comment: If I undertand right : you need to display the right price on the title and the discount price on price column ?

Comment: No, i just want to show actual product price with title.
with out adding additional cost. like showing in price column, not total column price.